# Get video title from ytdl-core

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, video, youtube

I have ytdl-core downloaded and im using it with discord.js. I have a command that plays a YouTube video's audio into voice chat. Does anybody know a way I can get JUST the string of the video title from a link, or a simple way to get the title? Even easier would be just a way to get the title of the video from the link somehow. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you are looking for is `getInfo()`

https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core#ytdlgetinfourl-options-callbackerr-info

```
getInfo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A', function(err, info) {
  console.log(info.title) // "Adele - Hello"
});
```

Answer (score 5):

While you're streaming the audio through Node.JS pipes to a [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

You could use the already fetched information to make it efficient!

```js
var stream = YTDL('https://youtu.be/H7NuU-dDRLU');

/* Spit-out information when recieved */
stream.on('info', (info) => {
    console.log(info.title);     // Tobu - Roots
    console.log(info.video_id);  // H7NuU-dDRLU
});
```

> **Note:** If just needed to fetch information then use [`YTDL.getInfo`](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core#ytdlgetinfourl-options-callbackerr-info) instead.

Comment: I want to use title and id as name of the file, how can I do that in my code:
video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('videos/'+ info.title+ ' '  +info.video_id+'.mp4'));
I know it has to do with async call, but maybe you know soluttion

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function below, it works perfectly for me:

```
function getTitleVideo (videoUrl){
   return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      ytdl.getBasicInfo (videoUrl, (err, info) => {
            resolve (info.title)
      })
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getInfo()` as `info.title` is no more valid due to some changes in `ytdl-core`.

Example:

```js
getInfo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A', (info) => {
    // console.log(info.title) Alert! this is Wrong
    console.log(info.videoDetails.title) // "Adele - Hello"
});
```